# Php html is printing as it is on the page

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I have and html string like this : 
`&amp;lt;div class=&quot;short-description&quot;&amp;gt;                    &amp;lt;h2&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/h2&amp;gt;                    &amp;lt;div class=&quot;std&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;This &amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;1-1/2 in by 25 ft. Deluxe In-Ground Pool Vacuum Hose&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt; fits most in-ground residential and commercial pool cleaning applications. The continuous spiral wound construction of the vacuum hose provides excellent flexibility and strength. The smooth spiral design inner wall also allows for maximum efficiency of water flow.&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;em&amp;gt;**Color may be blue or grey**&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;                &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;`

I encoded it using `htmlentities` and again decoding it using `html_entity_decode`  it decoding successfully but when on the web browser it coming like : 
`"<div></div>"` the html is printed out on the page.

I know this is not related to encoding the html is saved in db table any idea on this.

Thanks

Comment: Show some PHP code so we can see if there's a problem somewhere else... `html_entity_decode` should do the trick... but since you've mentioned you are using it, it's likely to be something else causing the issue

Comment: It looks like you've encoded it twice. `<` was encoded to `&lt;`, and that was then encoded to `&amp;lt;`. So you need to decode twice to undo this.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks barmer... u got the case decoding twice solved the problem. Post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have double-encoded your entities. Post the PHP code if you can't figure it out, but it looks like you are encoding an already html-entity-encoded string.